# how to extract a variable in the middle of process to another process multiprocessing python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

i made a program in python that runs 2 processes simultaneously, but i want to take a variable in the middle of the first process to the other process, like passing that variable from function to function. Here is a code that is working but the output is not what i expected.

```
import multiprocessing
import time

t=0
def countup():
    global t
    while t<25:
        t=t+1
        time.sleep(1)
        print("count",t)

def what():
    global t
    globals().update()
    while True:
        time.sleep(3)
        print ("the count reached ",t)

if __name__=="__main__":
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=countup,args=())
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=what, args=())
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

the output is shown as this

```
count 1
count 2
the count reached  0
count 3
count 4
count 5
the count reached  0
count 6
count 7
count 8
the count reached  0
...
```

the variable "t" is not updating, but both processes are working at the same time. The expected results suppose to be like this:

```
count 1
count 2
the count reached  2        
count 3
count 4
count 5
the count reached  5
count 6
count 7
count 8
the count reached  6
...
```

am i missing something ? is there something wrong in my code?

Comment: Processes can’t share state like this. Multiprocessing offers various means of communicating between processes, use these to pass information.

Comment: so, when the first process working on a variable like "t", the second process will not see any change in "t" ? then ,,, if that so ,,, how can i make that happen?

Comment: Have you read the tutorials of the multiprocessing module documentation? It lays out various options. It also contains a section on this, although it very explicitly warns against doing so: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#sharing-state-between-processes

Comment: thanks , i will read that. and will return to here if i got any solution

Answer (score 0):

i solved it , according to #deets , using Queuing or pipes to exchange variables is the key.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def f(q):
    q.put([42, None, 'hello'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    print(q.get())    # prints "[42, None, 'hello']"
    p.join()
```

amazing that i used this method for synchronized count printing between 2 different processes that work simultaneously. ... just wow

here is the code:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process,Queue
import time

t=0
def countup(q):
    global t
    while t<25:
        t=t+1
        time.sleep(1)
        print("count",t)
        q.put(t)

if __name__=="__main__":
    q = Queue()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=countup,args=(q,))
    p.start()
    while (q.get()<15):
        time.sleep(2)
        print("the count reached ",q.get())

    p.join()
```

the result is this

```
count 1
count 2
the count reached  2
count 3
count 4
count 5
the count reached  4
count 6
the count reached  6
count 7
count 8
...
```